# Distortion after import a PNG on Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

When I import a PNG file with transparency to Inkscape, for example an icon with size 48×48, I always get a distortion, even done if I export the bitmap, it is the same.

Someone else with the same problem?

Comment: You should post a screenshot, it would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There may be more than one position to set - both the base position and any transforms you have applied to it.

Try turning on and locking to the grid (press #) before you import.  This should have the same effect as Drasil's suggestion, but it avoids a lot of potential confusion.

To verify that it worked, turn off the grid (press # again) and set your zoom to 100%.  The image should not look blurry or distorted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's related, but sometimes I have problem with imported pixel images if they're not at rounded positions.

Try to set the image at rounded positions, for exemple x=140 and y=206 instead of 140.22 and y=206.3645 ?

Comment: I have the same distortion, even done I set rounded posititions